# The URL of images on my website changed after being set as featured image

Tags: plugin-development, images, urls, thumbnails

When I upload the image, it is https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/image-name.jpg
After I set it as a featured image, it is like:
https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/image-name-pbpc1q6exttjkxpm1we8ytyicduwun0uk12ffhoguk.jpg
Why it doesn't show its original URL? Anyone can help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install some plugin to handle the image process? it's probably coming from there.

Comment: Elementor, I'd guess from the image URL. It's probably making its own resized version to fit the featured image size.